# Manually handle assembly loading

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly

I have a bunch of some larger assemblies that I would like to exclude from installation but and be able to download from website to local exe folder on demand - when executeable needs/tries to load. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event for that purpose. That event occurs when the resolution of an assembly fails (e.g. missing as in your case). Then you can download the remaining assemblies and load them by one of the `Assembly.Load` methods. See the corresponding MSDN documentation for details.